# ffmpeg ошибка "повреждение входного пакета" при чтении данных из стандартного ввода

Tags: c++, qt, ffmpeg

Я записываю видео из матриц кадров. Но результат выглядит как-то вот так. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом получаю следующие сообщения об ошибке

```
[rawvideo @ 000002bd2390ca40] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 279).
[in#0/rawvideo @ 000002bd2390c680] corrupt input packet in stream 0
[rawvideo @ 000002bd23928cc0] Invalid buffer size, packet size 31190 < expected frame_size 1440000
[vist#0:0/rawvideo @ 000002bd2390e500] [dec:rawvideo @ 000002bd23927880] Error submitting packet to decoder: Invalid argument
```

Ориентируясь на последнее сообщение предполагаю что ошибка содержится в командной строке.

```
 cmd = QString("C://ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -s 800x600 -pix_fmt bgr24 -i - -r %1 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p C://ffmpeg/test/%2").arg(FPS).arg(OutFileName); // *.mp4
```

Comment: 1) Ошибки возникают в конце записи или в процессе? 2) Проверяете ли вы в своём коде, что кадр, который вы запихнули в ffmpeg, действительно запихнулся в него целиком?

Comment: 1. В конце. 2. Нет, делаю вот так.  fwrite(exported.data,1,800*600*3, outw) Вот, здесь видимо, проблем не возникло. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72884815/how-to-stream-frames-from-opencv-c-code-to-video4linux-or-ffmpeg